# kbmmemtable EOutOfMemory error after LoadFromDataset

Tags: delphi

I am using Delphi 7 Enterprise under Windows 7 64 bit.
My computer had 16 GB of RAM.

I try to use kbmMemTable 7.70.00 Professional Edition (http://news.components4developers.com/products_kbmMemTable.html) .

My table has 150,000 records, but when I try to copy the data from Dataset to the kbmMemTable it only copies 29000 records and I get this error: `EOutOfMemory`

I saw this message:
https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/memtable/conversations/topics/5769,
but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: What happens if you try to add the same number of records to your KbmMemtable by generating them in code?

Comment: Delphi 7 can only access up to 2GB of memory, no matter how much your computer has installed. It's a 32-bit application. How many columns in each row of your dataset? And what size are the columns? 150K rows is not a lot, unless they're all very wide character columns. Please [edit] to include your table's column definitions, so we have an idea of how large a *record* is in your table.

Comment: thank you very mach, my dataset has only 2 row like this CodeArt (Varchar (15)  NUmBL integer) . and I  load from my dataset by this code.    KBMTable1.LoadFromDataSet(IBQuery1,[mtcpoStructure]);

Comment: MartynA wrote :
 
What happens if you try to add the same number of records to your KbmMemtable by generating them in code? –     please how how can I do this?

Comment: Well, if you have persistent TFields defined (using the ObjectInspector) on your memory table, then you can do it by a series of calls to .InsertRecord().  That takes a list of field names and an array of variants which supply the values.  See the D7 Online Help for TDataSet.InsertRecord.

Comment: do you need to load all the records at once ? could you load and process them a thousand at a time ?

Answer (score 0):

An out of memory can happen of various reasons:

- Your application uses too much memory in general. A 32 bit application typically runs out of memory when it has allocated 1.4GB using FastMM memory manager. Other memory managers may have worse or better  ranges.
- Memory fragementation. There may not be enough space in memory for a single large allocation that is requested. kbmMemTable will attempt to allocate roughly 200000 x 4 bytes as one single large allocation. As its own largest single allocation. That shouldnt be a problem.
- Too many small allocations leading to the above memory fragmentation. kbmMemTable will allocate from 1 to n blocks of memory per record depending on the setting of the Performance property .
  If Performance is set to fast, then 1 block will be allocated (unless blobs fields exists, in which case an additional allocation will be made per not null blob field).
  If Performance is balanced or small, then each string field will allocate another block of memory per record.

best regards
Kim/C4D

Comment: Thank you Kim/C4D for your answer , but what can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: @Touhami, did you manage to get an answer to your problem?  I have the same issue when trying to load about 34k records that has been saved locally in a binary stream with this component.